# What is the ES6 Promise equivalent of jQuery Deferred's 'always`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, es6-promise

I have something like the following:

```
getUser("foo").then(handleSuccess, handleError).always(tidyUp);
```

`getUser` returns a jQuery Deferred object.

I understand from [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) that I can convert the Deferred object to a native Promise using `Promise.resolve`, so I can write

```
Promise.resolve(getUser("foo"))
  .then(handleSuccess)
  .catch(handleError)
```

The [Promise API](http://Promise%20API) doesn't offer an `always` method though, so I'm wondering how that should be handled.

Is it as follows?

```
 Promise.resolve(getUser("foo"))
  .then(handleSuccess)
  .then(tidyUp)
  .catch(handleError)
  .then(tidyUp)
```

Answer (score 19):

I think the following is what you're looking for:

```
 Promise.resolve(getUser("foo"))
  .then(handleSuccess, handleError)
  .then(tidyUp)
```

tidyUp will be always called. See the following jsbin for the full example: http://jsbin.com/lujubu/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Yes, that would work thanks. You also made me realise that I can also just do `Promise.resolve(getUser("foo")).then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError).then(tidyUp)`, i.e. keeping the `catch`.

Answer (score 3):

Use your `always` function as the handler for `resolve` *and* `reject` to ensure it will always be called.

```js
function getUser(result) {
    switch (result) {
        case 'good':
            return Promise.resolve();

        case 'bad':
            return Promise.reject();

        case 'ugly':
            return new Promise(() => { throw new Error() })
    }
}

function handleSuccess() { console.log('success') }
function handleError() { console.log('error') }
function tidyUp() { console.log('all tidy now') }


Promise.resolve(getUser('good'))
    .then(handleSuccess)
    .catch(handleError)
    .then(tidyUp, tidyUp);

Promise.resolve(getUser('bad'))
    .then(handleSuccess)
    .catch(handleError)
    .then(tidyUp, tidyUp);

Promise.resolve(getUser('ugly'))
    .then(handleSuccess)
    .catch(handleError)
    .then(tidyUp, tidyUp);

// success
// error
// error
// all tidy now
// all tidy now
// all tidy now
```

[Promise API Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)